# Django DRF APITestCase post url results in 404 error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm learning DRF test cases, and in my test.py file, my URL in the client post-call is coming back in a 400 status error:

Here's my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

#from rest_auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("api/", include("profiles.api.urls")),
    path("api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls")),
    path("api/rest-auth/", include("rest_auth.urls")),
    path("api/rest-auth/registration/", include("rest_auth.registration.urls"))
]

from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here's my test.py file

```
import json
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from rest_framework import status
from profiles.models import Profile
from profiles.api.serializers import ProfileSerializer


class RegistrationTestCase(APITestCase):

    def test_registration(self):
        data = {"username": "testuser1", "email": "test@localhost.app", "password1": "A41&14all", "password2": "A41@14all"}
        response = self.client.post("/api/rest-auth/registration/", data)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

It appears that the line `self.client.post....` fails to find the endpoint.
What am I missing?

thanks!

Comment: try to go on registration url in your browser and check that if you're getting same error or not